# MS Access before update cancel event not working for unbound combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combo box in Access that has a row source that is bound to a table but does not share the same record source as the form. I want the user to be able to select items from the drop down box but I want to give them a warning before they change stuff and if they say no then undo the changes like this:

```
Private Sub cboSelectAddress_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim prevAddress As String

    'prevAddress = Me.cboSelectAddress.Value

    If MsgBox("Are You sure you want to change the value of the combo box?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "CTNO change altert") = vbYes Then

        'DO SOMETHING
    Else
        'Me.cboSelectAddress.Value = prevAddress
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

As soon as I change the value of the combo box the value of the combo box changes and then and only then does the before_update event fires.

To mitigate this, I tried to store the value of the address box before change and set it back to the original value if the user selects `NO` but this produces an error as well because it tries to go through the before update event itself. As you can see I have commented out that portion of the code.

Comment: Have you step-debugged? You will see that prevAddress is receiving the new value entered, not old value. So even if you did not get error, would not set combobox to previous input.

Comment: Yeah you are right just realized that

Comment: Why do you need to micro-manage user input to UNBOUND control?

Comment: I just learnt that the before update event fires after the combo box value change even in the bound control. To mitigate this I added :  `Me.cboSelectAddress.Undo` if the user selects no.

Comment: You can write answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I just learnt that the before update event fires after the combo box value change even in the bound control. To mitigate this I added : `Me.cboSelectAddress.Undo` if the user selects no